# How can I make GIT to default to my home folder?

Tags: git

I've just installed GIT on my work machine (Windows 7) connected to the domain at work. When I start the GIT bash it starts on "H:" instead of in my home folder. I think this could be a problem when I'm not connected to the domain since the .ssh folder is located on "H:" instead of my home folder. I have set HOME environment folder to point to c:\Users\MyName, but that doesn't help. My HOMEDRIVE environment variable points to "H:" and the HOMEPATH to "\", but I can't change those.

First question: Will there be an issue when I'm not connected to the domain and the .ssh folder is on a domain drive?
Second question: How do I fix it? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just have bash `cd` to your home directory when you start it with like `cd /home/dan` in `.bashrc`.

I did this in cygwin once as it put my home directory in `/bin/%SOMETHING%`.

Comment: Thank you, just keep it simple :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too. Just wanted to add that the .bashrc file goes into the folder that bash is starting in. Example, my bash starts in H:\, but I want to be in C:\code, so I placed the .bashrc file in H:\ w/ one line: cd /c/code