# Git sees the system profile as home instead of the user home folder (Windows 7)

Tags: git, windows-7, ssh, cmd, bitbucket

I am new to Git and am following [this Bitbucket tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git) for initial setup. In the [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) window, it shows me as brnt@brntslaptop, but if I enter

```
ls -a ~/.ssh
```

I get this output:

> ls: /c/windows/system32/config/systemprofile/.ssh: No such file or directory.

I assume it has something to do with me being an administrator or having [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) disabled, but I am not sure of the best way to proceed.

[This answer is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313342/how-can-i-make-git-to-default-to-my-home-folder)- but I don't think it is a good idea to redirect from the system folder to a user folder, especially if another user has the same issue. Other similar answers seem to do a symbolic link or similar for a solution. But I haven't found one that involved the system profile.

I also considered changing the shortcut properties "Start In:" from %HOME% to %USERPROFILE%, but `~` still seems to resolve to %HOME%.

Is this behavior normal? What is the proper way to make "~" or %HOME% resolve to my user directory?

Answer (score 3):

Just change %HOME% (or actually $HOME, as %HOME% most likely is not set at all).

By default, `<git-install-dir>\etc\profile` sets $HOME to %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% if they are set and point to an existing directory, or to %USERPROFILE% otherwise.

So, you could edit that file, locate the line

```bash
HOME="$HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH"
```

and remove it or add an `#` in front of it to force %USERPROFILE% to be used instead.

Alternatively, add a line anywhere after this block explicitly setting *HOME* to what you want it to be.

In newer versions of Git that line may no longer be present.

I have added the following at the very top of my `etc\profile` (it is very specific and ugly, but it works):

```sh
# Homefix start
HOME=/c/Users/myusername/
HISTFILE=$HOME/.bash_history
export LANG=en_US

# Normalize HOME to Unix path
export HOME="$(cd "$HOME" ; pwd)"
# Homefix end
```

The `export LANG...` line can be ignored. I have it there to get English text in menus and buttons in Git GUI and [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk), because IMO to translate Git commands adds no value, only confusion.

Comment: Having run into a similar issue, I couldn't locate that line in profile anymore - either something broke my installation, or it may have moved.

Comment: Thank you @RickMoritz, for pointing that out. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I installed the Windows creators update and %HOME% stopped resolving correctly. I fixed it by explicitly setting HOME=%USERPROFILE% for my user.

Answer (score 0):

I landed here looking for a reason why on the same Windows machine, one user could use

```
git config --list --global
```

from the Windows-PowerShell commandline, but another user could not.

Basically, there is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#home), `$HOME`, set in PowerShell pointing to the correct location; however this is not the variable `git.exe` is looking for. It wants the [environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-5.1#saving-environment-variables-with-setenvironmentvariable), `$env:HOME`, to be set.

In order to resolve it going forward, on the user who was not able to list their global settings we ran the following Windows-PowerShell command:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('HOME',$env:USERPROFILE,'User')
```

Note: Here I've used the `'User'` scope instead of the `'Machine'` scope as shown in the documentation, because this typically does not require admin rights.

Comment: What is the gist of this? Why does it work? How persistent is this? Only for the current session of PowerShell (window)? Or permanently changing the global or user setting in Windows? Are administrator rights required or not for the PowerShell session? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66462223/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).