# Can't find a way to shell_exec('git pull') due to ssh key

Tags: git, ssh

So I've setup a `git pull` Webhook from my server.

When I run a test I'm ending with :

> Host key verification failed. 
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

However I have a ssh-key well inserted since I can `git pull` from the directory.

### Edit :

Okay so I think it is due to apache user problem.

I tried to sudo `-u www-data git pull origin master` but I have the following error :

> Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts).

With those permission :

```
root@vps362370:/var/www/.ssh# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2  777 root 4096 Feb  3 14:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb  3 10:06 ..
-rw------- 1  777 root 1675 Feb  3 14:48 id_rsa
-rw------- 1  777 root  404 Feb  3 14:48 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1  777 root    0 Feb  3 14:58 know_hosts
root@vps362370:/var/www/.ssh# cd ../
root@vps362370:/var/www# ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Feb  3 10:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Feb  3 12:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2  777 root 4096 Feb  3 14:58 .ssh
```

What kind of permission should be set? (I tried 777 or 600 but none seems to work).

### Edit 2 :

I've manage to add git to my known host by 
`usermod -a -G www-data root`
Then

```
chgrp www-data /var/www/.ssh
chmod g+rwxs /var/www/.ssh
chmod 777 /var/www/.ssh/known_host
```

But now I got :

> Permission denied (publickey).

Even after specifically adding my /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to github deploy key.

My .git/config file :

```
root@vps362370:/var/Smart-Pix# cat .git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:Smart-Pix/Smart-Pix.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Have you tried ssh with verbose options from toe server to the repo server? It might help you identifying communication problems.

Comment: Hum the thing is I do not connect to the server but only send a Post Request when pushing.
I don't see where I could use verbose for debugging purpose :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BitBucket: Authentication failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692721/bitbucket-authentication-failed)

Comment: Does this means you clone with HTTPS? In this case the SSH key is not used.

Comment: @Tom Nup nup, I'm never using https

Comment: The fact you are dealing with `/var/www` means you are using HTTP for communications with the remote repo. HTTP does not use SSH keys, it uses login + password or a similar authentication. I don't think it is a good idea to have a `.ssh/` folder in `/var/www`, and in any case `.ssh/`folder must have 700 permissions. What is the content of your local `.git/config` file?

Comment: I do not really had the choice for the folder. It is automatically set to this.
I've edited with my config