# 'git clone' command work from terminal but not with php shell_exec()

Tags: php, windows, github, ssh, shell-exec

I am getting following error when i git clone using php shell_exec() on windows server. My git version is  git version 2.11.1.windows.1.

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists
```

But working fine through git bash and command prompt. I have configure ssh properly.

The problem is the  file which i have created is in the c:/inetpub/example.com/deploy.php

I am running following code in php file.

```
shell_exec('cd c:/inetpub/ &&  "c:/Program Files/Git/bin/git" clone sshURL  2>&1')
```

Can any one suggest any solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Any difference with `passthru('cd c:/inetpub/ &&  "c:/Program Files/Git/bin/git" clone sshURL  2>&1')`?

Comment: @sensorario.. still no change. same issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BitBucket: Host key authentication failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576718/bitbucket-host-key-authentication-failed)