# Host key verification failed on first ssh connection

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to log with ssh on my EC2 instance with a new dual-booted ubuntu 16.04. It's the first time i'm logging in with this client, so there is nothing in .ssh/known_hosts to be deleted, as it is suggested in many other posts like this one.

When I run :

**ssh -i "my_key.pem" ubuntu@servername.amazonaws.com**

I get:

```
The authenticity of host 'servername.amazonaws.com (serverip)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:***************************.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed.
```

Since i can log with the exac same key from putty on my windows computer,and also from a mac with the same key, this doesnt seem to be key-related.

Anyone out there to help? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: i installed putty on linux, since it was working on windows. Doesnt work either.

nmap localhost gives me port 22 open. 
nmap my.ip doesnt.

I tried to ssh to another address, and same results on ssh and putty :(

EDIT2: not a duplicate of [BitBucket: Host key authentication failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576718/bitbucket-host-key-authentication-failed)

**Problem solved:** it was just me who only pressed Enter on "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" and not typing yes. Thanks @Kenster

Comment: At the "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" prompt, what do you do?

Comment: I just pressed enter supposing it was yes on default. Now i feel dumb but at least my problem is solved, adding yes works. Thanks @Kenster you just solved my problem!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BitBucket: Host key authentication failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576718/bitbucket-host-key-authentication-failed)

Answer (score 3):

If you do not get any option to continue to connect and it fails permanently, then you could use the command with StrictHostKeyChecking=no option like following :

**ssh -i "my_key.pem" ubuntu@servername.amazonaws.com -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no**

Comment: that's best answer to me