# Windows 10 Host key verification failed

Tags: windows, git, ssh

The company I work on has it's own git server.

When I execute "composer update" I get the error "Host key verification failed."

I have tryed the solutions from here [Git error: "Host Key Verification Failed" when connecting to remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository)
 after deleting the contents on my C:/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts.

A knew key was created in this file, after I executed the solution from the link above, but I still get the same error...

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BitBucket: Host key authentication failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576718/bitbucket-host-key-authentication-failed)