# Php exec git pull script with ssh doesn't work but doing it manually works

Tags: php, git, ssh

I'm trying to make a script where I can Git pull on my ubuntu server after push to Bitbucket repository. I've setup ssh keys to Bitbucket and it works to do git pull command on the repository but it doesn't work when I try it from php exec.

I've tried chmod commands like /.ssh/bitbucket_rsa like 775 and 777 and chown -R www-data:www-data/.ssh without any luck.

Response:

```
array (
 0 => 'Host key verification failed.',
 1 => 'fatal: Could not read from remote repository.',
 2 => '',
 3 => 'Please make sure you have the correct access rights',
 4 => 'and the repository exists.',
 )
```

Code:

```
    public function gitPull() {
    try {
        exec("cd " . env("REPO_PATH") . " && git pull 2>&1", $output);
        Log::info($output);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e);
    }
    http_response_code(200);
}
```

Comment: What user is that code running under? See the output of `exec('whoami');` to be sure.

Comment: 'www-data' is the output

Comment: and what user did you set up the ssh keys with?

Comment: I set up the ssh keys with root

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BitBucket: Host key authentication failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576718/bitbucket-host-key-authentication-failed)

Answer (score 1):

I stack with the same problem working with github:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com | tee github-key-temp | ssh-keygen -lf -
cat github-key-temp >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
cat github-key-temp >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

But that is not all, with next command you can check what is goes wrong (run it throught exec or shell_exec (save out put to some log):

```
ssh -vT git@github.com 2>&1
```

So, with help of privious command, i understand that in my case: cron run's command via php script, but duaring ssh connection it could not find my keysfile (i have custom name for that file):

```
cd /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/
sudo touch <some_name>.conf
sudo echo 'IdentityFile ~/.shh/<custom_key_file_name>' > <some_name>.conf
```

Or try to add full path to location of your keyfile (~/ = current user home dir).
You can check cron user by runing, this can helps to:

```
shell_exec('whoami');
```

P.S. I have no idea if this solution is enough secure. but i think fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are stuck with the fact that the user www-data can not establish the SSH connection to the git server. I think the simplest was is to create a home directory for the www-data user and create a .ssh directory with the proper permissions, a config file and the key file in there. You could always test the setup as root with

```
# su - www-data
$ cd <to your repository>
$ git pull
```

Google for "SSH connections without password" to set it up correctly. And also be aware that SSH refuses to use a key file if the permissions are to loose.

Answer (score 0):

```
Host key verification failed.
```

means that ssh could not verify the host key, most likely because there's no `known_hosts` file in www-data's home/.ssh directory that contains the expected host key for your repo's server.

There's at least two ways to fix that:

- Use [`ssh-keyscan` as described over on Serverfault.se](https://serverfault.com/a/316100/310439):

  ```
  ssh-keyscan -H [hostname] >> /path/to/www-data's_home_directory/.ssh/known_hosts
  ```

  You only need to do that once (unless the key changes), but you should check that the key is indeed correct after you run `ssh-keyscan`.
- Set the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable before running `git`. You can use this to have ssh use a different `known_hosts` file:

  ```
  export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/path/to/known_hosts"
  ```

  Note that the above assumes shell syntax (e.g. Bash), you may need to adjust for PHP, particularly the `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND=` part.