# Bitbucket Cloud SSH Host Keys Rotation

Tags: git, bitbucket

I read this https://bitbucket.org/blog/ssh-host-key-changes but they explained it so poorly. Can someone actually write what needs to be done to make it work? I did all the steps from their site and I still cannot push, pull or fetch.

I can switch to GitHub, no problem there. But if someone can write what actually needs to be done to make it work that would be great.

Comment: you need to add their 2 new keys: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256  and ssh-ed25519 in your known_hosts file . read  steps on "WHAT YOU NEED TO DO" section

Comment: Add where? On my laptop?

Answer (score 3):

The main commands are:

```bash
ssh-keygen -R bitbucket.org
curl https://bitbucket.org/site/ssh >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

You can do so from a bash session (even on Windows, since Git for Windows comes with `%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\bash.exe`).

> Add where? On my laptop?

Yes, you need to do so from every machine you want to authenticate to Bitbucket.

See more at "[Bitbucket: Host key verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76266042/6309)".