# Unable to ssh to Bitbucket from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, bitbucket, openssh

I am unable to `git`/`ssh` to the Bitbucket host. I tried debugging, and noticed that `ssh` is stuck after `set_sock_tos`.

- `ssh -vvv -T git@bitbucket.org`: It times out trying to connect to the IP address *bitbucket.org* resolves to.
- `ssh -o IPQoS=none -vvv -T git@bitbucket.org`: The same result.

For what it's worth, I am able to verify connection to `github.com`. What am I missing?

```
penSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/gvaish/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/gvaish/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "bitbucket.org" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup bitbucket.org:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [2406:da00:ff00::22c0:3470] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IPV6_TCLASS 0x10
debug1: connect to address 2406:da00:ff00::22c0:3470 port 22: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [2406:da00:ff00::3403:4be7] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IPV6_TCLASS 0x10
```

`netstat` shows it's stuck on `SYN_SENT`:

```
tcp6   0   1 2601:641:4001:fb2:34898 2406:da00:ff00::3403:22 SYN_SENT
```

Comment: bitbucket changed theirs keys. check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76516728/bitbucket-cloud-ssh-host-keys-rotation?noredirect=1#comment134913158_76516728

Comment: I should have added - already updated the `known_hosts`.

Comment: Perhaps you can force an ipv4 connection with `AddressFamily inet` in your `~/.ssh/config` file and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: you are resolving `bitbucket.org` to an IPv6. Did you try IPv4 ? like `ssh -4 git@bitbucket.org`.. Also can you do `dig -4 bitbucket.org` and get a valid IP?